# how to make vba-word work in vba-excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

the following two lines

```
Dim curTasks As Tasks
Set curTasks = Application.Tasks
```

get the list of all current tasks and work like charm in `vba-word` but not in `vba-excel`.
is there a way to port it into `vba-excel`?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do in Excel? There is no concept of `Tasks` in Excel (if you are talking about Office 2007/2010). In fact, even the `Application` object is only relevant to Word as well.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin i am trying to make those two lines work in excel

Comment: They won't work. Excel doesn't have `Tasks`...

Comment: @EkoostikMartin i am not sure what alternative situation you had in mind! if Excel had `Tasks` and above code were working would i be asking this question on stackoverflow? if it helps this is a paraphrase of my question: how can i get the list of all current tasks in excel?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin `even the Application object is only relevant to Word as well` every Office program that I'm aware of that supports VBA has an `Application` object. Or am I misreading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, the Excel object in VBA doesn't have the concept of tasks. You can do the below though in an Excel Module (although I'm still not sure why you would do it):

```
Dim curTasks As Tasks

Dim wrd As Word.Application

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set curTasks = wrd.Tasks
```

NOTE: you have to add a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library to get this to work

Comment: i could make your code work only by defining `curTasks` and `wrd` as `Variant`. I am not sure if this was necessary or i am doing something wrong. thank you.

Comment: You need to a reference to the Word Library. `Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library` That is how you can use VBA to interact between Apps. In the reference list you will see object libraries for Outlook, Access etc.

Comment: @AlistairWeir can you elaborate? how can i make a reference to `Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library` ? how can i look up this reference list that you are referring to?

Comment: In VBA app, go to "Tools" menu and select "References...". Then pick the checkbox for `Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library` and click "OK"

Comment: +1 Ekoostik.. I should have explained how to do what i described